# Toad: speeding up a very slow intellisense

Tags: oracle, toad

When I write the alias of a table and press the dot key Toad suggest me the column names of that table.

The operation lasts very different from one computer to others. From seconds to minutes.

How can I spped it up?

In "Toad Insight Objects" options which should I check for column names suggestion?

Comment: Try restarting Toad.  But when in doubt, reboot.  Sad, but for windoze, I'm not joking.  See if that clears up your issue.   Plus, if you have Toad up for a while, you'll eventually get access violations and need to restart Toad anyway.

Answer (score 2):

After putting dot when you see the pop down which shows the suggested columns, please click on the options button next to refresh. This will take you to Options screen.

In that screen goto Editor -> Code Assist. Now you can see "Delay popups" on the right side. Reduce the milli seconds and then apply and click ok.

This will speep up intellisense

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is toad caches the results of intellisense. And I assume going from one computer to another the cache does not exist when you first hit the table. Therefore, toad begins to query the data dictionary for the list of objects. It should be quicker second time around when you query that object.

You can also manually refresh by using the picklist-dropdown. There should be a refresh button in the top left.

Comment: Is there any way to force caching for all tables?